# Is there any benifit of providing column name in schema of Cassandra column family instead of not providing any column information in schema?

Tags: schema, size, cassandra

I have say column family Users , in which i want to store names of users.
So i will be inserting "user-name"="nameValue" pairs into Users column family. Following are the two approaches

1. If I do not mention the "user-name" as column name in Users while creating columnFamily and insert such a million columns to Users CF and
2. If I create the CF Users with column metadata including "user-name" as column name in schema and insert such a million columns

Will there be any difference in size taken(size of sstables on disk) and time taken(to insert into cassandra) by both these approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column_metadata field is only really used by cassandra for two things. Secondary indexes and column value validation. It doesn't sound like you are creating a secondary index (which obviously would use more space and affect insert time)

So the benefit you would be getting is validation that your column values conform to a specific type. This won't increase the size of your CF at all. Obviously there is one extra step taken when inserting that column, but the performance impact there should be miniscule.

Another small benefit to using the column_metadata is simply for aesthetic purposes/documentation of the cf and what it is used for. If you want to use it for this or for validating column values go ahead.

Comment: further, you can update the column metadata after data is loaded to add or remove the secondary index.

Comment: @nickmbailey : So you mean disk size utilized by sstables in both the approaches will be same provided no secondary indexes used.